# rabbitmq grouping a set of messages

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, grouping, message-queue

I have got many servers, which publish into one RabbitMQ queue. I have also got three readers, which consume this queue. The readers are supposed to read a set of messages and treat it as one "unit-of-work". So, for example if READER-1 reads msg-1 & msg-2. This reader needs to mark these two messages as one-group so that if it dies before committing these messages, one of the two remaining READERs gets msg-1 & msg-2 instead of the default behavior, which is msg-1 is read be READER-2 and msg-2 is read by READER-3. 
Once a set of messages are marked as one group, they should be sent to only one reader.

So, is there a way for a READER to mark a set of read msgs as one group?

Comment: RabbitMQ doesn't support message groups

Comment: Thank you, I was not able to find anything with this regard in the Docs either. I just was hopping that some RabbitMQ experts might have an idea or work around.